# Resilience4j Retry+Spring Boot 2 application.yml config not applied

Tags: spring-boot, circuit-breaker, retry-logic, resilience4j

I'm using Resilience4j @Retry combined with @CircuitBreaker. 
I use annotations in SpringBoot 2 and my configuration is in *application.yml*.
I have a fallback method in the @Retry annotation, but not in the @CircuitBreaker (That's the way to make them work together because of the aspect order as per my findings).

The @CircuitBreaker works fine using my configuration in application.yml. 
The Retry also works but does use only the default config values and do not reflect the values in the *application.yml* (EX.: maxAttempts is 3 instead of 5).

Any idea what I may be doing wrong here, please?

In the code:

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "myService")
@Retry(name = "myService", fallbackMethod="myServiceFallback")
public HttpEntity myService(final String url) throws MyException{ 
//My logic 
}
```

[The config in application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qf25.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted out.

I was using
*maxAttempts* in the configuration as mentioned here :
https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry

Where the proper config name is *maxRetryAttempts* as shown here:
https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml

```
resilience4j.retry:
    configs:
        default:
            maxRetryAttempts: 3
            waitDuration: 100
...
```

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot documentation can be improved. Keep in mind it's community-driven. You can always improve it as well ;)
https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#configuration